# How to get a Collection of TreeMap values and sort it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, treemap

Exacly as stated in the  subject I have got a map `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();` and I would like to get the Collection of values then sort it by length of the `ArrayList` and print on console only those which are longer than 3.

I did it, **it works** but it is ugly. Can I do it better?

My solution:

```
Object[] values = map.values().toArray();

        Arrays.sort(values, new Comparator<Object>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                ArrayList<String> a1 = (ArrayList<String>) o1;
                ArrayList<String> a2 = (ArrayList<String>) o2;
                return -(a1.size() - a2.size());
            }

        });
        for (Object o : values) {
            ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) o;
            if (list.size() >= 3)
                System.out.println(list.size() + ": " + (ArrayList<String>) o);
        }
```

Comment: If you only want to print the arraylist whose length is > 3, then why sort it?

Comment: Why `Object[]`? You know the type. It is `ArrayList<String>` ...

Comment: I know the type and when I cast it ther I get an exception... done right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what Rohit Jain hinted at is that sorting the array and then iterating it anyway is pretty expensive, *if the only purpose of sorting is to skip the entries not meeting the length criteria*.

You could as well only iterate it and check in each iteration if the element under inspection is long enough to be printed or not.